# Async or parallel tasks - C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an application where I need to do two I/O tasks: get a GPS location, retrieve some data over Bluetooth. Both tasks can vary in time to complete, and can take many seconds. To improve the speed of the application I want to kick-off both activities at the same time, and then wait for both to complete before proceeding.

If I do this:

```
bool locationStatus= await GetCurrentLocation();
bool vehicleStatus = await GetVehicleData();
```

does the second function get kicked off, or is it only the UI that is not blocked?

Do I need to invoke parallel tasks instead?

Comment: There was a duplicate question a few hours ago. There are a *lot* of similar questions with great explanations. Please search for a solution *first* before posting.

Comment: I know it is not the fast answer you seek, but I believe you should invest in studying this. https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: By asking for something that's already been answered 100 times you *won't* get good answers - people become tired of answering the same thing after a while. Instead of the great explanation they wrote 1 year ago they'll only post a short answer

Comment: @itdoesntwork that link is unrelated to the question. Rx isn't meant for *asynchronous* programming anyway, it's meant for event stream processing, even if *other* languages like Java use it this way because they lack `async/await` support

Answer (score 6):

You are directly awaiting the first function. If you want to let the functions complete asynchronous, you will have to put the `await` at the position where you need the variables.

For example:

```
var locationStatus = GetCurrentLocation();
var vehicleStatus = GetVehicleData();

if (await locationStatus && await vehicleStatus)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```